# Netlist simulation: Illegal "lvalue" in this context

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I am trying to simulate synthesized (into D flip-flop) physical register file (PRF). The testbench in the behavioral form works fine. But after synthesis, some of the internals have been renamed by the tool, and basically, I am trying to assign the value generated by the functional simulator into the PRF. This is done in the initial block. Below is part of the testbench code. (This is a sample code and not fully complete in terms of loading all the bits into all the register files):

```
 1050 reg  [`SIZE_DATA-1:0]          test [`SIZE_RMT-1:0];
 1051 integer x, y, z;
 1052 
 1053 always @(*)
 1054     begin
 1055         for (x = 0; x < `SIZE_RMT; x++)
 1056             begin
 1057                 for (y =0; y < `SIZE_DATA; y ++)
 1058                     begin
 1059                         coreTop.registerfile.PhyRegFile.ram_reg_95__63_.D = test[x][y];
 1060                         z = y;
 1061                     end
 1062                     z = z + 1 ;
 1063             end
 1064     end
```

The description of the `ram_reg_95__63_` module is below:

```
 DFF_X1 ram_reg_95__63_ ( .D(n44180), .CK(clk), .Q(ram[6143]) );
```

where, `n44180` and `ram[6143]` are wires.

The error that I get:

```
ncelab: *E,WANOTL (simulate_gate.sv,1059|72): A net is not a legal lvalue in this context [9.3.1(IEEE)].
```

I am not sure what/where I am missing.

Comment: "not a legal lvalue" means "you are not allowed to assign to it". As far as I know, you can only assign to `reg`s inside `always` blocks (I'm not exactly sure for SystemVerilog, though).

Answer (score 1):

You are never allowed to procedurally assign wires in Verilog or SystemVerilog. A few things you can do:

1. Use the `force` statement to assign the `D` inputs and wait for one clock cycle for them to get captured, then `release` it.
2. Look inside the `DFF_X1` and see if you can procedurally the `Q` register inside it.
3. Substitute the `DFF_X1` module with your own behavioral model where you can assign to the `Q` variable.